# How to add apps to INSTALLED_APPS for tests?

Tags: python, django

Currently, we can only run `./manage.py test autocomplete_light` in the provided [test_project](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/v2/test_project) because it has added them to [INSTALLED_APPS](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/v2/test_project/test_project/settings.py).

Due to user demand, my goal for v2 was to enable tests in user projects. The first thing to do was to move [example apps](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project) into a [subdir of the module](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/v2/autocomplete_light/tests/apps).

Now, all that I need is to be able to add them and their urls during test cases.

I tried [overriding settings with the provided method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#overriding-settings) but this overrides settings **after** the database was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the tests with a special settings.py, by setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable. This special "testsettings.py" can import * from the normal settings.py, and then add the necessary extra apps to INSTALLED_APPS.

Remember that settings.py files are just ordinary Python modules, so you can add any logic you want to get the list of extra apps from somewhere.

Comment: Good idea ! Users won't be able to run the tests with ./manage.py test and no --settings flag right ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup, what users and user projects are exactly and so on, but you can probably setup a small helper script that calls the test runner using the right settings file?

Comment: That could work, I'm going to try that. Thanks for your feedback !

Answer (score 0):

Django provides the `modify_settings()` context manager for easier settings changes:

```
class TestSomeApp(TestCase):

    def test_some_app(self):
        with self.modify_settings(
            INSTALLED_APPS={"prepend": "some_app"}
        ):
            # ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.modify_settings